# Ontology model with nested nodes(Lists) by Apache Jena API

Tags: api, rdf, jena, owl, rdfs

How could I create the Ontology Model by Jena API programmatically for array of Strings

```
 String["First_1", "Second_2"]
```

that model.print(System.out) produces this:

```
   <owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://example.com#test_one">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://example.com#test"/>
    <rdfs:range>
        <rdfs:Datatype>
            <owl:oneOf>
                <rdf:Description>
                    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#List"/>
                    <rdf:first>First_1</rdf:first>
                    <rdf:rest>
                        <rdf:Description>
                            <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#List"/>
                            <rdf:first>Second_2</rdf:first>
                            <rdf:rest rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#nil"/>
                        </rdf:Description>
                    </rdf:rest>
                </rdf:Description>
            </owl:oneOf>
        </rdfs:Datatype>
     </rdfs:range>
    <rdfs:label>Test one</rdfs:label>
  </owl:DatatypeProperty>
```

Comment: What do you mean by nested nodes? This is RDF/XML syntax, simply write the Jena model to disk in that format. Or do you mean how to create the example programmatically, i.e. create a complex datatype as the range of a property.

Comment: Yes, how to create this RDF/XML programmatically. I think it is DataRange, but I am not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you edited your question the problem is more understandable. For the future, the first entry point is indeed the [Jena documentation](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/ontology/). And for a Java developer indeed the [Javadoc](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/index.html) is the most informative source.

I just did it for the range of the data property, domain and label works similar by applying methods of the [`OntModel`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/ontology/OntModel.html) resp. [`Model`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/index.html):

```java
import org.apache.jena.ontology.DataRange;
import org.apache.jena.ontology.DatatypeProperty;
import org.apache.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import org.apache.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class RangeExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String NS = "http://example.com#";

        String[] values = new String[]{"First_1", "Second_2"};

        OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM);

        DatatypeProperty testOne = m.createDatatypeProperty(NS + "test_one");

        DataRange range = m.createDataRange(
                                m.createList(
                                        Arrays.asList(values)
                                                .stream()
                                                .map(v -> (RDFNode) m.createLiteral(v))
                                                .iterator()));

        testOne.addRange(range);

        m.write(System.out);
    }
}
```

The generated model will be valid OWL, the Protege editor renders it as follows:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Everything is OK except <rdfs:Datatype> replaced by the <owl:DataRange>

Comment: Hm, I see - but does this really matter? There are different ways of serializing the same semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Use the RDF/XML pretty writer:

`RDFDataMgr.write(System.out, model, Lang.RDFXML)`

If calling `model.write`, it's called "RDF/XML-ABBREV"

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/io/rdf-output.html

The exact output layout varies depending on the data - it is always outputting the same triples, which is what matters most.

Comment: The problem is how to create such Ontology model in Java from String[] with data, not to print it.